# Overwrite log file using grep

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Hi I would like to ask how can I overwrite complete.log with same file but getting certain characters.

***current log file:***

```
CompleteJob:test1.sas:
CompleteJob:test2.sas:
```

***new log file:***

```
test1.sas
test2.sas
```

I used grep and  >> to do so;

```
grep "CompleteJob" complete.log | cut -f2 -d: >> complete.log
```

but my result looks like this:

```
CompleteJob:test1.sas:
CompleteJob:test2.sas:
test1.sas
test2.sas
```

Comment: Try `sed -i.bak 's/.*:\(.*\):$/\1/'  complete.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try one more option which will work in any version of awk.

```
awk -F":" '{print $2}' Input_file  > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

Making field separator as colon(:) and printing the second column of Input_file to output file named temp_file. Then using mv(move/rename) command to renaming temp_file to Input_file again. NOTE here && means if in case first command succeed then only it should rename temp_file to Input_file.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed  -i -r 's/^.+:(.*):.*/\1/g'  file

cat file
test1.sas
test2.sas
```

Comment: can you please explain the "sed  -i -r 's/^.+:(.*):.*/\1/g'  file" command ?

Comment: Anything between () is capured and later referred by \1 or \n. This is called back reference.so here i have capured everything between two columns. @ashish

Answer (score 0):

The optimal approach:

```
sed -i 's/^[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1/' complete.log
```

- `[^:]*` - matches any character except `:`

Comment: I encountered this error. 
`Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...]`

I tried redirecting it to new file, but i still got same error.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk (gawk) you can do:

```
gawk -F: -i inplace '{print $2}' complete.log
```